# Apply XSLT on XML get the ancestor value based on current for-each loop count

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to XML and XSLT. What I am trying to do is generate a CSV file by applying an XSLT.

This is my XML file:

```
<people>
<person>
    <codes>
        <code>53-8907</code>
    </codes>
    <first-name>Matt</first-name>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <state>TX</state>
        </license>
    </licenses>
</person>
<person>
    <codes>
        <code>66-8907</code>
    </codes>
    <first-name>Mike</first-name>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <state>NY</state>
        </license>
    </licenses>
</person>
<person>
    <codes>
        <code>53-8907</code>
        <code>66-8907</code>
    </codes>
    <first-name>Rob</first-name>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <state>TX</state>
        </license>
        <license>
            <state>NY</state>
        </license>  
    </licenses>
</person>
</people>
```

This is the XSL I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:csv="csv:csv" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/people">
    <xsl:for-each select="person/licenses/license">
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::person/codes/code"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::person/first-name"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="state"/>
        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is what Output I want:

```
53-8907,Matt,TX
66-8907,Mike,NY
53-8907,Rob,TX
66-8907,Rob,NY
```

This is what I am getting:

```
 53-8907,Matt,TX
 66-8907,Mike,NY
 53-8907,Rob,TX
 53-8907,Rob,NY
```

Can someone guide me how to count the for-each value for license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code renders the requested result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:csv="csv:csv" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="text"/>
   <xsl:template match="/people">
      <xsl:for-each select="person/licenses">
         <xsl:for-each select="license">
            <xsl:variable name="Pos" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::person/codes/code[position() = $Pos]"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::person/first-name"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="state"/>
            <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You're welcome. You may want to use &#10; instead of &#13; (as Mathias suggested), or even &#13;&#10; depending on your exact needs.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution, which stores things in variables and uses `concat()`.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:csv="csv:csv" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="person">

        <xsl:variable name="first-name" select="first-name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="licenses" select="licenses/license"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="codes/code">
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
             <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,',',$first-name,',',$licenses[$pos],'&#10;')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Text Output**

```
53-8907,Matt,TX
66-8907,Mike,NY
53-8907,Rob,TX
66-8907,Rob,NY
```

Try it online here: http://xsltransform.net/94hvTze/3.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your issue :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:csv="csv:csv" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/people">
        <xsl:for-each select="person/licenses">
            <xsl:for-each select="license">
                <xsl:variable name="licensePos" select="position()"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::person/codes/code[position()=$licensePos]"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::person/first-name"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="state"/>
                <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I did here is keep the `position` of the license in a variable, than when checking for the parent code, make sure it have the same position.

See it in action : http://xsltransform.net/94hvTze/1

Comment: Even if I fix your malformed XSLT code, the result is not what the OP described: http://xsltransform.net/94hvTze.

Comment: The problem with this code is that the for-each selects persion/licenses/license, and the positions you get for that sequence is not what you want.

Comment: Sorry about that, should have tested it before... Fixed the stupid error.

Comment: No, the last `xsl:text` is not empty, there is a newline character in it.